# how to run an application using 3g

Tags: android

friend's
   I  need help on running an application in 3G,the application works well in wifi,but also i need to work it on 3G also,what i have to do work in 3G.is there anything i need to add in manifest file for 3G?

help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an application that connects to the internet using something different than the HTTP protocol ? And, what network carrier are you testing your app on ? There might be some limitations set by carriers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all you need is the internet permission. How the device is connected to the internet is nothing you need to care about. You just need to handle timeouts and offline modes, which normally doesn't happen on wifi.

Comment: This depends though as most networks block certain web requests on 3G.

Comment: @Mr.MGS: This is a duplicate Question refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827143/how-can-i-use-a-3g-internet-connection-in-my-android-app

Comment: i set internet permission in manifest file,but it still stucky.

Comment: stucky? Don't forget: wifi is mostly faster than 3g